# How do I create several reports with the same layout but different query inputs in Access 2010?

Tags: sql, report, ms-office, ms-access-2010, reporting

This feels like it should be very simple but I just can't figure it out. I've made a report based on a SQL query in Access 2010. Now I want the same report layout and parameters but the input from a different query.

Basically, the query takes people and other values from a specific department. I want to make a report for each department.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Just solved it. It was very simpel. I had just minimized the section bar. 
1.Open the data access page in Design view 

2.Double-click the section bar (Make sure you its not hidden to the side) 

3.In the RecordSource property box, select a record source from the list. 

Maybe this helps someone else.

Comment: You should make your comment the answer of your question, so others can find it easily in the future.